Meta App Events have zero match rate with the connected product catalog
I am using a mobile SDK from Facebook to sent App Events. I am focusing on three essential ones - view content (fb_mobile_content_view), add to cart (fb_mobile_add_to_cart), purchase (fb_mobile_purchase). I have been through many iterations now and was not able to match the events with the products catalog. The documentation is very inconsistent and I am failing to understand what the app events should look like to be able to match the catalog. I am hoping there is someone out there that has been through the same and managed to find a solution.
Here are my findings so far after researching the topic for weeks now. They may or may not be correct:

Using the SDK results in parameters called i.e. "fb_content_id" as opposed to "content_id" that lot of documentation references. Documentation is mostly focused on either web or server-side implementation and there is no troubleshooting information for apps that I was able to find.
Existing troubleshooting mentions using "content_ids" (plural form), so I added that as extra parameter to be sure.
There are two parameters "fb_content_id" and "fb_content". From what I learned, they should never be sent together but only one of them.

Based on my research, I am tracking the parameters below. You will see I am duplicating some of them to include a prefixed and a non-prefixed version hoping some of this gets picked up.

"fb_content_id" = "123456" for single item or "fb_content_id" = "['123456','456789']" for several items
content_ids = <the same value as fb_content_id>
"fb_content_type" = "product"
"content_type" = <the same value as fb_content_type>
"fb_currency" = "USD"
"currency" = <the same value as fb_currency>
"_valueToSum" = 12.99
"fb_num_items" = 1

Some of the above parameters are handled by the SDK:

FBSDKAppEventParameterNameContentID,
FBSDKAppEventParameterNameContentType,
FBSDKAppEventParameterNameCurrency,
FBSDKAppEventParameterNameNumItems

The price and currency also get tracked as part of SDK methods logEvent and logPurchase.
Unfortunately, we are still at zero percent match rate and are looking for answers. I had a long email conversation with Meta Pro team, which turns out to have no expertise in anything related to app. The Facebook's developer support responds with an error when trying to submit a request and support page that Meta gave me via X.com does is silent to my requests. I feel like I exhausted my options and hope to find help here. So thanks in advance to anyone that will feel like contributing here!
